# How to design and implement game according to state diagram?

Tags: design-patterns, state, diagram

This is my state diagram:

[image: state diagram]

My game change states only after user action (only exception is "time's up").

I don't know best practice how I should implement my mechanism, which will help my swich between states.

Should I define proper enum? Whether each state should have own method? How to control whether changed state is acceptable?

Any tip is welcome!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the state design pattern: [State pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern)

That way every state is its own object and handles the state transitions.